# Gevent WSGI not handling requests concurrently

Tags: python, flask, server, wsgi, gevent

## UPDATE

Took Grahams advice and abandoned Gevent as my WSGI, I instead went with mod_wsgi-express and so far everything is working as expected. I need to do some more research into Gevent to determine exactly why it's not working, but there's a very real chance that it is because the Teradata compiler is not compatible with the monkey_patch and thus gets blocked/serialized.

I'll leave the question up for other wanderers though, cheers.

## ORIGINAL

Creating a Flask application as a front-end GUI for users to manipulate data in a Teradata database.

I have the application up and running with Gevent, but I'm realizing that it is not handling multiple user's requests in a parallel manner..

An example is User A is running a ~10 second query against the database, and User B won't even be able to access the home page until User A's query is complete. As soon as the query comes back, User B's home page will load and until then User B's browser will just hang at a blank loading screen.

I would expect each user accessing the WSGI server would have their own seperate instance of the application and be able to navigate around the pages regardless of other user's queries. I figured the Gevent capabilities would help when it came to many user's accessing the database at the same time.

I feel like this is a combination of
1) Me not configuring the application correctly
2) Me not understanding Gevent correctly

Here is my setup, where have I gone wrong?

## app.wsgi

```
from gevent import monkey, sleep

monkey.patch_all()

import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/fotlflaskapp')

from app import app as application
```

## **init**.py

```
from gevent import monkey, sleep

# need to patch sockets to make requests async
monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

with open(os.getcwd() + '/flag.txt', 'r') as file:
    flag = file.readline()

if flag == 'prod':
    production = True
else:
    production = False

from app import views
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer

if production is False:
    app.run(debug=True)
else:
    server = WSGIServer(('10.2.33.216', 8888), app)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
```

I use the following command to call the .wsgi file, which points to the **init**.py

```
python3.4 /var/www/flaskapp/app/app.wsgi
```

I absolutely cannot figure out why the app is functioning in a completely serialized way. If multiple users are accessing the app, why do they each have to wait for each other even to just access pages?

Comment: What Python client are you using to talk to the Teradata database? Calling ``monkey.patch_all()`` is not some magic wand that will result in everything working in an async manner. If an package you are using has a C extension component and that is calling out to backend services, then it will block the whole application. The monkey patching only works for pure Python code. Unless you properly understand how gevent/eventlet works and the risks in using it, it is better to avoid it and use a traditional WSGI server.

Comment: Using the teradata python module, but yes you are correct in that I should probably be using a traditional WSGI server.  Switching to mod_wsgi-express (which I believe you made?) and hoping it can handle the concurrent database requests.. we shall see. Thanks for the comment!